# How to deploy ant.design full stack on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, create-react-app, antd, react-scripts

I switched my styling from material-css to ant.design. To do so I had to change my client package.json to have `react-app-rewired` instead of `react-scripts`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

When I push this to heroku it can't find the command. Why is this?

I get the following error from my heroku build log:

```
      > react-app-rewired build

sh: 1: react-app-rewired: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-app-rewired build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-01-27T03_26_58_947Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! infinity2o_server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the infinity2o_server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
```

Answer (score 1):

my problem was having `"react-app-rewired": "^1.4.0"` as a `"devDependencies"` instead of being in `"dependencies"` for production :)